# Importing all images from folder, location address is in a local file

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to import images to use them in a React project... Images are stored locally and I have to get the information from a local.js file, here's a sample of what I have and it works in that way, by adding the import image and using it in my component code

```
import image from './images/image.png'

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={image} alt={props.data.name} />
            <h1>{props.data.name}</h1>
            <p>{props.data.description}</p>
            <button>OK</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

However, I want to change `<img src={image} />` for `<img src={props.data.photo} />` to take the data from my local file and change the component dynamically, as I have 18 photos

This is the parent component

```
import dataFile from './scripts/data.js'

const parentComponent = dataFile.map(property => {
        return (
            <ChildComponent
                data={{
                    key: property.id,
                    name: property.name,
                    photo: property.photo,
                    description: property.description
                }}
            />
        )
    })
```

This is the local file

```
const dataFile = [
  {
   id: 1,
   name: sample1,
   photo: './images/image.png',
   description: Lorem ipsum
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   name: sample2,
   photo: './images/image2.png',
   description: Lorem ipsum
  },
{
   id: 3,
   name: sample3,
   photo: './images/image3.png',
   description: Lorem ipsum
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use:

`<img src={props.data.image} />`

But should be:

`<img src={props.data.photo} />`

Because when you're calling `ChildComponent`  you're sending `photo` in `data`

Comment: Thank you, it was my bad on my sample code, however I checked my code and it contains the same property name, I edited the sample code to avoid confusion